# JQuery does hover shows all elements, need help with parent refrence or $this

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, hover, jquery-hover

What I have is a listing of images and content they are wrapped in div tags called views-row-1, views-row-2, views-row-3 ect

- div1 .views-field-field-inthepress-icon-fid .field-content
- div2 .views-field-markup .field-content

once div1 is hovered then i make div2 visible using jquery (set to none in css), using css div2 goes on top of div1 and then i hid div1

I have hidden the content and using JQuery I display it, the problem is that when i hover all content is displayed for all listings!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".views-field-field-inthepress-icon-fid .field-content").hover( function() {
        $(".views-field-markup .field-content").css('display','block');
    }, function() {
        $(".views-field-markup .field-content").hide();
    });

    $(".views-field-markup .field-content").hover( function() {
        $(".views-field-markup .field-content").css('display','block');
    }, function() {
        $(".views-field-markup .field-content").hide();
    });
});
</script>



<div class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first">

<div class="views-field-field-inthepress-icon-fid">
<span class="field-content"><img src="Untitled-2.jpg" /></span>
</div>

<div class="views-field-markup">
    <span class="field-content">
    <div class="inthepress-bold"><span class="date-display-single">21/01/2011</span> BBC News Article UN</div>
    <div id="inthepress-body"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed lobortis blandit iaculis.</p></div>
</span> 
</div>
</div>

<div class="views-row views-row-2 views-row-odd views-row-first">

<div class="views-field-field-inthepress-icon-fid">
<span class="field-content"><img src="Untitled-2.jpg" /></span>
</div>

<div class="views-field-markup">
    <span class="field-content">
    <div class="inthepress-bold"><span class="date-display-single">21/01/2011</span> BBC News Article UN</div>
    <div id="inthepress-body"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed lobortis blandit iaculis.</p></div>
</span> 
</div>
</div>

<div class="views-row views-row-3 views-row-odd views-row-first">

<div class="views-field-field-inthepress-icon-fid">
<span class="field-content"><img src="Untitled-2.jpg" /></span>
</div>

<div class="views-field-markup">
    <span class="field-content">
    <div class="inthepress-bold"><span class="date-display-single">21/01/2011</span> BBC News Article UN</div>
    <div id="inthepress-body"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed lobortis blandit iaculis.</p></div>
</span> 
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".views-field-field-inthepress-icon-fid .field-content").hover( function() {
    $(this).parent().next().css('display','block');
}, function() {
    $(this).parent().next().hide();
});
```

This gets the parent of the hovered element, and then finds the next sibling. If your HTML will always follow the structure in your question, this should work fine.

Note that you could use `.show()` instead of setting the CSS `display` property.

Comment: See my edit. Note that this will only work if your HTML always follows the structure in your example. If not, let me know and I'll modify it.

Comment: I am trying to display a hidden element, so when i mouse over, i make the div appear on top of the div i hovered then hide the hovered div

 .views-field-markup .field-content {
 color:#FFFFFF;
 font-size:.85em;
 background-color:#1B8F9E;
 position:relative;
 width:105px;
 top:-169px;
 left:0px;
    height: 155px;  
 padding:10px;
 display:none;
}

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".views-field-field-inthepress-icon-fid .field-content").hover( function() {
        $(this).css('display','block');
    }, function() {
        $(".views-field-markup .field-content").hide();
    });

    $(".views-field-markup .field-content").hover( function() {
        $(this).css('display','block');
    }, function() {
        $(".views-field-markup .field-content").hide();
    });
});
</script>
```

Just change the target to $(this). when you using  $(".views-field-markup .field-content") it selects all elements with those classes.
It's good to use  $(".views-field-markup .field-content") to hide elements. because you don't want to show any element with those classes when mouse is out.

Comment: no luck, it doesn't do anything remember .views-field-markup .field-content is another div that on mouse over i want to put on top of the DIV i hover

Comment: So set ID for them or use  $(".views-field-markup .field-content")[0] for first and so...